# Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception When trying to update MySQL database in Java

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I have a sale table in jframe form, user adding a row one at a time.

I want to reduce **instock** in MySQL table **saleifo** by reducing **qty** column in the table.

Code segment for save and print button ;

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tableSale.getModel();

    if(model.getRowCount()==0){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have nothing to Print or Save ");

    }else{
       int save = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you really want to Save the Invoice Data ?","Save Confirmation",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
       if((save)==0){

        try{

            String saledate = ((JTextField)dayChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
            String invoice = InvoiceNo_txt.getText();
            String citems = countitems_txt.getText();
            String tDis =totalDiscount_txt.getText();
            String ntotal = NetTotal_txt.getText();

            //setting data to saleinfo db table
            try{
                String sql = "Insert into saleinfo (SaleDate,InvoiceNo,TotalItems,TotalDiscount,NetTotal)values (?,?,?,?,?)";

                pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);


                pst.setString(1, saledate);
                pst.setString(2, invoice);
                pst.setString(3, citems);
                pst.setString(4, tDis);
                pst.setString(5, ntotal);

                pst.execute();

            }catch(Exception e){

            }


            //redusing stock in db

            int rcount = tableSale.getRowCount();

            String idsale = (String) tableSale.getModel().getValueAt(rcount, 0);

            String sql0= "select * from druginfo where ItemID=?";

            pst0=conn.prepareStatement(sql0);
            pst0.setString(1, idsale);

            rs0= pst0.executeQuery();

            if(rs0.next()){
                String instock = rs0.getString("InStock");

                int nowstock=Integer.parseInt(instock);
                int soldqty = (int) tableSale.getModel().getValueAt(rcount, 3);

                int newstock = nowstock - soldqty;

                System.out.println("new :"+newstock);

                String sqlupdate= "update druginfo set InStock='"+newstock+"' where ItemID='"+idsale+"'";
                pst=conn.prepareStatement(sqlupdate);
                pst.execute();
                System.out.println("Done");

            }
```

But shows an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 2
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)  at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:648)
at com.bit.project.Newsale.saveprint_btnActionPerformed(Newsale.java:1039)
at com.bit.project.Newsale.access$1300(Newsale.java:57)
at com.bit.project.Newsale$16.actionPerformed(Newsale.java:683)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
```

Line 1039 is `String idsale = (String) tableSale.getModel().getValueAt(rcount, 0);`.

How to fix this?

Comment: Table has **2** rows (`rcount == 2`), so `getValueAt(index, 0)` is valid for index `0` and `1`, but not `2`, which is what you're passing.

Comment: JDBC advice: prepare all statements in advance when you create the connection. There is no point in creating a prepared statement each time you click a button. Also, prepared statements for update should also be used with the `?` placeholder, not by concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

At line 1037 you assign the number of visible rows in the table to the int rcount, which in this case is 2. However on line 1039 you use this value to attempt to get the value of "row 2, column 0" from the table model.

As row and column indices start from 0, and there are only two rows numbered 0 and 1, it's no wonder there is a problem when you ask for row 2!

If your intention is to get the value of the cell in the first column and last row of the table, then you need to change line 1039 to:

```
String idsale = (String) tableSale.getModel().getValueAt(rcount-1, 0);
```

You are already checking that `rcount` > 0 by the time execution reaches this point so this shouldn't cause trouble. Except...

It's worth noting that if the table has a RowSorter attached to it, then the number of **visible** rows (sa returned by `tableSale.getRowCount()` may well be less than the number of **actual** rows in the underlying table model (as returned by `tableSale.getModel().getRowCount()`, and the row number of the last visible row may be quite different in the table model. You can convert visible row numbers to model row numbers using `tableSale.convertRowIndexToModel()`. Which would make line 1039:

```
String idsale = (String) tableSale.getModel().getValueAt(
    tableSale.convertRowIndexToModel(rcount - 1), 0);
```

In your code you initially check to see if there are any rows in the model. But at line 1037 you read the number of visible rows. If there is a  RowSorter with a filter then this may return a value of 0 even if there are lots of rows in the model. Which would cause trouble here as well.